# Primary Key of Parent Table not updating in the Child Table in Hibernate Envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a parent table **DataVO**, which has a list like this

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name= "DATA_NUM", nullable = false)
@AuditJoinTable(name="EP_DATA_STUS_AUD")
private List<DataStatusVO> dataStatusVOList = new ArrayList<DataStatusVO>();
```

**DATA_NUM** is the primary key of the Parent Table.

Everything works fine except the fact that the **DATA_NUM** is null in the **DATA_STUS_AUD** table. 
    But, **DATA_NUM** populates in the Parent and Join Table("**EP_DATA_STUS_AUD**").

I get this error, When I remove the insert=false and update=false from

```
@Column(name = "DATA_NUM")
private String dataNum;

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.envers.DuaStatusVO column: DATA_NUM (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Any clue on How to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Inserts the child elements first and then updates the Foreign Keys. In your case the first a record into Data_status is inserted and then hibernate updates the Data_num.

Envers interceptor is fired only for save, savaOrUpdate function not for Update function. In your case when the Data_Status is inserted into to the table without the Data_num, the envers interceptor is fired and it makes copy of it and inserts into Audit table.

Then when the hibernate updates the foreign key, envers is not called. Hence you won't get any Data_Num in the audit tables.

The join tables are takes the primary key value of parent and child tables from the audit tables, along with rev info and inserts the record. So in your case, Data_num from parent table and Data_Status_num from your child table.

As far as the error is concerned, if you want to keep the same parent and child relation, and remove the insert = false, update = false, Remove the nullable = false from @JoinColumn(name= "DATA_NUM", nullable = false) in the parent child relation.